# Is there an English word for "the cover of a group's photo" on which we can usually write names?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

At school or at family events, we can sometimes get photos of the group we represent.

Such photos are often placed in a paper/card cover on which are lines ready to write the names of the persons that are on the photo.

Is there any single term to represent this object?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest "photo *jacket*" or "photo *sleeve*."

> Would you please inscribe the photo sleeve?
>
> Would your son prefer "J.D." or "James Dean" on our photo jacket?